# Can I set the margin-bottom property of an element to = dynamic height of a sibling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm building a site with a fixed (not sticky) `footer`, kept behind the main page using `z-index` so that it only appears once the user scrolls to the bottom of the content. It's revealed by assigning a `margin-bottom` value to `.pagewrap` that is equal to the height of the `footer`.

Because the `footer` height is dynamic (changing with content and viewport width), I can't give the `.pagewrap` div a fixed `margin-bottom` value in px. Rather I need to fetch the current height of the `footer` element and apply that value to the `margin-bottom` of the main div, presumably using JS or jQuery (although a pure CSS solution would be a revelation, obviously).

Important: because the re-flow of text in the `footer` can cause the element's height to change, the solution to this problem needs to happen on resize AND on load.

I can find plenty of resources to match height using JS and jQuery, but these all apply the value to the `height` property of the targeted element. Here the value is needed for a different property.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sL0brv3j/

html:

```
<div class="pagewrap">
  <p>Scroll down</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Fixed position, behind the .pagewrap element</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.pagewrap {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 64px; /* should be set to = dynamic height of footer*/
  z-index: 1;
}

footer {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto; /* changeable value */
  z-index: 0;
}

footer p {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `position: sticky` on the footer to do this. If you want to do this pure CSS than it's very difficult to use `position: fixed` because it's outside the normal document flow so it has no idea about the elements inside the document flow, but `position: sticky` does.

Using `bottom: 0` to put it at the bottom of the page and the `z-index: 0` to have it underneath the main content.

It's just the reverse of a sticky header that is on top of the page.

```
footer {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Edited JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7a8b51z/1/

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you. So simple and so pleasingly obvious I didn't even consider it. Pure CSS, too! I have learnt something today.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to listen for `load` or `resize`. You should be setting this where you are setting the footer.

You can set margin-bottom by doing

```
myElement.style.marginBottom = "" + calculated value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking advantage of the `height()` property in jQuery. Create a variable with this value and then use it to apply the `margin-bottom`.

```js
var h = $("div").height();

$("h1").css("margin-bottom", h);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Title</h1>

<div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqeu6k79/)**

Comment: Yes! This is what I was trying to do, but I didn't have the necessary knowledge to take a value from one property and apply it to another. I went pure CSS since that route was also suggested but this is going in the notes for future reference, thanks.